# LLDB expr command not changing variable

Tags: xcode, lldb

I'm attempting to use Xcode's LLDB console to change a variable.  I want to do this using the breakpoint's debugger command so my program execution is never halted and I want to change the variable manually.  I'm using Xcode 6.

Using the expression command, I can see the variable changing in Xcode.  My breakpoint is positioned on the check for myBoolValue == NO.  If I inspect the value of myBoolValue after issuing the expression command, Xcode tells me the value is NO, but the if-statement never evaluates correctly, and "do neat stuff" is never executed.

[image]

My LLDB expression to change the variable:
    **expr myBoolValue=NO;**

When I execute this command, lldb echoes the following:
    **(BOOL) $0 = NO**

What am I missing here, why am I seeing that myBoolValue change, but the code inside the if statement is never executed?

EDIT: If I change the value using Xcode (not using the LLDB expr command), the if-check still does not evaluate properly.  I'm sure Xcode is issuing the same command underneath the hood that I'm issuing from the lldb prompt, but it's still odd that the if-check never evaluates properly.

EDIT 2: Here is the assembly code. I have edited the code in my question to match the code for this assembly.  Basically the same thing, but with a NSLog statement as my neat stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a disassembly of where you're stopped?

I suspect that the line tables are being funny here, telling LLDB that the location to stop for line X is between the CMP myBoolValue,NO and the JNEQ otherNotNeatPlace. If that were the case, then yes, changing myBoolValue after it's been checked-for, would not make any difference

With that said, do not try to change values from the Xcode UI unless you're trying to set really trivial numeric values. It's a known limitation where currently unless you're trying to write a numeric value back to a variable whose value is somewhat "numeric", editing the value won't really work.

EDIT: Yeah, my comment stands. You're comparing a register value to #0. You're stopped after myBoolValue has been loaded from the stack into a register. However, the location of myBoolValue is still supposed to be the stack location thereof. That means your edit will go on the stack but it's too late for that change to alter the register. Hence the result.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've edited my original question to post the assembly. I also made a slight adjustment to the code, changing the get neat stuff method to a call to NSUserDefaults, and the body of the code to a NSLog statement.

Comment: One thing I was hoping to see was the little ">" symbol for your stopped-at location. It looks like you would be in either of these two spots
Ltmp1:
    cmp r1, #0 <-- HERE
    bne LBB0_2 <-- OR HERE

One thing I see is interesting though.. you're comparing "r1" to #0. Can you do

(lldb) frame var -L -- myBoolValue

If we are told (by debug info) that myBoolValue is somewhere on the stack (likely in debug builds), we will definitely change the value on the stack, but we won't know to change the value in "r1", so even though "myBoolValue" is edited, its copy in r1 won't be affected

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking for.  I've updated the question to show where the program is halted with a screen shot of the assembly

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your file is compiled with optimization?  Often if there is any optimization a local variable may exist on the stack and a copy that is being operated on is in a register.  The debug information will only tell lldb about one of these copies -- usually the in-register one that is being operated on right now -- and so lldb may be modifying the register version but the compare is done from the stack memory one.

I'm just guessing, but that kind of scenario could lead to the behavior you're seeing.  Like Enrico suggests, the disassembly of this function would clear up what is going on.  In addition, when you're stopped at the place of interest, the output of

```
(lldb) image lookup -va $pc
```

will show where lldb *thinks* all of the variables are currently stored (based on the information in the debug info).  We may be at an instruction boundary like Enrico suggests, or we may have multiple copies of the variable value and the debug info only tells us about one of them.

Usually building at `-O0` (no optimization) avoids these kinds of problems.  When in doubt, reading the raw disassembly instructions is always helpful to understand what is actually going on.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I should have mentioned this in my original question.  Optimizations for my debug build are set to none.